# Why FullCalendar doesn't display hours beside?

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar

The calendar doesn't display hours beside . 
i have uploaded a picture and put the code to understand the problem more 
how can i correct it ?[image]

**Code javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var date = new Date();
        // the code display the calendar
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // the header
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            lang: 'fr',
            buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
            editable: true, // resize event
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            minTime: '06:00:00',
            maxTime: '20:00:00',
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.find('.fc-title').append(" || " + event.type);
            },
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                //getting the clicked date from calendar
            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent) {
               // event clicked
            },
            // events redered in twig template 
            // I an working with symfony
            events:{{ events|raw }} 
        })
    });
```

Comment: What version of jquery, momentjs, fullcalendar? It seems to be working @ https://jsfiddle.net/2r7txkhv/1/ - have any css that may be hiding it?

Comment: thank you very much i'm using fc-time{ display: none;} it's working now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much i'm using fc-time{ display: none;} it's working now